# Plotly box plot doesn't display "median", "q1", "q2", "q3" labels

Tags: r, plotly, boxplot

When I run the following code:

```
plot_ly(y = ~rnorm(50), type = "box") %>%
  add_trace(y = ~rnorm(50, 1))
```

I get a boxplot as I should with the hover labels showing "trace 0, some number" for every point median, q1, q2,q3, min, max, but the label doesn't say which one is which.

The same example on the [plotly website](https://plot.ly/r/box-plots/) labels every point correctly 
"trace 0, median: some number", but for me it doesn't show "median:" and other labels(min, max...), just shows trace name and associated number.

my plotly version is ‘4.7.1’